# Don't allow Japanese double digit characters in Email Validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I took the regex below from [EmailRegex](https://emailregex.com/). But, if I input a Japanese double-digit is passing the validation. For example ハロー@hello.com is passing the validation.

How can I allow only ASCII, romaji characters, or single digits in my validation?

Regex:  `/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

Ideal scenario:

- attack.on.titan@gmail.com ✅
- black@clover.com ✅
- ハロー@ハロー.com ❌
- ハロー@hello.com ❌
- hi１２３@hello.com ❌

Here is my entire code, I'm using React:

`utils.tsx`

```
export const isEmail = email => {
  const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (re.test(String(email).toLowerCase())) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

`Component/index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import {isEmail} from '../utils'
export interface ComponentInterface {
 emailInput:string
 setEmailInput: (e: any) => void
}
 
const Component : React.FC<ComponentInterface> = (props:ComponentInterface) => {
 const [inputErrorState, setInputErrorState] = useState(false)
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    if (inputErrorState) {
      setInputErrorState(false)
    }
    props.setEmailInput(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleOnSubmit = () => {
    const isValid = isEmail(props.emailInput)
    setInputErrorState(isValid ? false : true)
  }
  return ( <div> 
           <input
            type='email'
            id='props.emailInput'
            value={emailInput}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
          ></input>
        {inputErrorState && (
          <p>Your error message</p>
        )}
 </div> );
}
 
export default Component;
```

Comment: Is `ハロー@hello.com` not a valid email address?

Comment: Try `^[A-Za-z0-9.]+@.+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Comment: Is this really a problem worth considering? Just *send an email*. There is your validation. What is the use of using a complex regex that disallows valid emails? On the flip side you also cannot use a regex to verify that the email is *incorrect* while being syntactically valid. For example if Fred Bloggs enters `fredblogs@email.com` he would have misspelled his last name (single `g`). That's not caught by the regex yet accepted.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana that blocks A LOT of valid emails.

Comment: You're going to upset users with valid emails which happen to fail your random validation...

Comment: @VLAZ, hmm... a lot of valid emails? how? Tell me an example

Comment: How does `^[A-Za-z0-9.]+@.+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$` this block a lot of valid emails?

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana let's start with `fred_bloggs@email.com`. Next is `fredbloggs+phd@email.com`. These are common and valid characters for emails. There are some that are less common but equally valid like `'` (e.g, an O'Brien might use it). There are also spaces, double quotes, just to name a couple more. And *then* we also have non-English characters like `ö`. Next up we have non-*Latin* characters - Cyrillic, Japanese, Chinese.

Comment: @VLAZ, ohh. I didn't know an email can containt those

Comment: @VLAZ, this matches more: `^[A-Za-z0-9-'.+]+@(.+)\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Comment: You are off better using `^.+@.+$`

Comment: Try: `^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"ハロー１２３]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/IVdrnd/1

Comment: The best regular expression to validate an email is `.+@.+\..+` to filter out obvious typos. Then, deliver an email to the address to actually verify it. Trying to validate an email address beyond a simple sanity check is pointless, and usually incorrect and hostile to users whose emails you didn't anticipate.

Comment: @meagar agreed. I once worked on a system where the requirement explicitly called for *no* email validation. The reason was that we had an email field but didn't use it for anything other than showing it in a form. And it was expected that end users might fill in something like "send an email to sale@company.com and use [URGENT] in the title". Users are actually decent email parsers already.

Comment: @VLAZ, I think `^[^\s]+@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$` is better.

Comment: @meagar `^[^\s]+@[^\s]+\.[^\s]+$`

Comment: @meagar that is not the right regex. This is `^[^\s\t]+@.+\.[^\s\t]+$a` better.

Comment: `^.+@.+\..+$` is fine, and what I use regularly in many production systems. Again, the quality of the regex doesn't matter because it's only catching obvious typos. Delivering an email is the actual verification.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana, unfortunately, the regex doesn't apply to all double-digit characters like はは日@gmail.com Any other suggestion? 

Answer (score 1):

In regex, inside [ ], if you use - you can specify a range. I noticed that you already deleted several characters from the email name. Now just add the range in unicode you want to delete.

like: `[^\u0080-\uFFFF]`

`/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"\u0080-\uFFFF]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"\u0080-\uFFFF]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`